# extract bezier equations from otf

Tags: fonts, bezier

I am looking to extract the bezier equations that makeup fonts using the otf file format
ideally, I would like the raw equations so I can manipulate and plot them I cant find information on this anywhere
does anyone have any clue how to do this?

Comment: In which language? Because there are tons of font parsers out there that will give you the vector outlines for font glyphs to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The font data doesn't include Bezier equations; it has positions for Bezier control points. See documentation for the 'glyf', 'CFF ' or 'CFF2' tables in the [OpenType spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/). [This page](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM01/Chap1.html) in Apple's TrueType Reference Manual provides the quadratic Bezier equations pertaining to control points for the 'glyf' table, though you could find the equations anywhere.

The 'CFF ' and 'CFF2' tables work somewhat differently, in that they have a binary representation for graphic instructions that originate in the Postscript language (similar to paths in SVG, if your familiar with that); but curves are represented as a sequence of control points for *cubic* Beziers.